# Sumar el valor de un input number y el valor de N numero de checkboxes, javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quiero sumar los valores de un `input` con nombre `monto_pagar` y el valor de multiples `checkboxes` (el número de checkbox generados va de 1 a N) y mostrarlos en el `input` con nombre `total_id`.

Mi problema ocurre cuando el número de `checkbox` es mayor que 1, solo suma el ultimo `checkbox` generado. Supongo que el problema está en la forma en que obtengo el valor del ID cambiante.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
    $precio=100000;
    $i = 1;
    $cuotas_pendientes=4; //Si el valor es a 1 me funciona correctamente, pero cuando es mayor de 1 es donde comienza el problema
?>
<form name="formulario">
     <label>Abono</label>
     <input type="number" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a abonar" onKeyUp="operacion()">
     <br>
     <?php while ($i <= $cuotas_pendientes) { 
        $id = "id_cuota".$i; ?>
        <!--EN CADA ITERACION CAMBIO EL NOMBRE DEL CHECKBOX Y DEL ID-->
        <input name="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox" onClick="operacion()" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo "Cuota ".$i.": ".$precio?></label>
        <br>  
        <!--He colocado la funcion dentro del WHILE ya que el ID va cambiando en cada iteracion-->
        <!--Lo intente poner despues de la funcion y obtengo el mismo resultado no deseado-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function operacion() {
            caja = document.forms["formulario"].elements;
            var numero1 = Number(caja["monto_pagar"].value);

            $("#<?php echo $id; ?>").on('change', function(){
                this.value = this.checked ? <?php echo $precio; ?> : 0;
            }).change();
            var numero2  = Number(caja["checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>"].value);

            caja["total_id"].value = parseInt(numero1)+parseInt(numero2);
        }
    </script>
    <?php  $i++; } ?>

    <label>TOTAL</label>
    <input type="text" name="total_id" placeholder="0">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería mas fácil que hagas lo siguiente, el input de monto total, puedes dejarlo así

```
<input id="montoTotal" type="number" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a abonar">
```

imprime los checkbox de la siguiente manera

```
<input name="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

remueve el script dentro del while, y coloca este código fuera del while

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".checkbox").on('change', function(){
        var suma_checkSeleccionados = 0;
        $.each($("input.checkbox:checked"), function(key, val){
            suma_checkSeleccionados += parseInt($(val).val());
        });
        $("#montoTotal").val(suma_checkSeleccionados);
    });
</script>
```

esta es la versión modificada, se me paso el input del abono

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$precio=100000;
$i = 1;
$cuotas_pendientes=4;
?>
<form name="formulario">
<label>Abono</label>
<input id="abono" type="number" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a abonar">
 <br>
  <?php while ($i <= $cuotas_pendientes) { 
    $id = "id_cuota".$i; ?>
    <input name="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo "Cuota ".$i.": ".$precio?></label>
    <br>
    <?php  $i++; } ?>
    <!--Probe colocanco el script antes del formulario y tampoco funciona-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sumChecks() {
        var suma_checkSeleccionados = 0;
            $.each($("input.checkbox:checked"), function(key, val){
                suma_checkSeleccionados += parseInt($(val).val());
            });
        return suma_checkSeleccionados;
    }
        $(".checkbox").on('change', function(){
            $("#montoTotal").val(parseInt($("#abono").val()) + sumChecks());
        });
    $("#abono").on('change',function(){
        $("#montoTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) + sumChecks());
    });
    </script>
    <label>TOTAL</label>
    <input id="montoTotal" type="text" name="total_id" placeholder="0" onchange="suma_final()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

pero aun no me funciona. aqui te dejo el codigo como quedo siguiendo tus instrucciones... ahora no me suma ningun dato.

No esta demas decir que deseo sumar el input name="monto" y los checkbox... y luego reflejar el resultado en el input name="total_id"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$precio=100000;
$i = 1;
$cuotas_pendientes=4;
?>
<form name="formulario">
<label>Abono</label>
<input id="montoTotal" type="number" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a abonar">
 <br>
  <?php while ($i <= $cuotas_pendientes) { 
    $id = "id_cuota".$i; ?>
    <input name="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo "Cuota ".$i.": ".$precio?></label>
    <br>
    <?php  $i++; } ?>
    <!--Probe colocanco el script antes del formulario y tampoco funciona-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".checkbox").on('change', function(){
            var suma_checkSeleccionados = 0;
            $.each($("input.checkbox:checked"), function(key, val){
                suma_checkSeleccionados += parseInt($(val).val());
            });
            $("#montoTotal").val(suma_checkSeleccionados);
        });
    </script>
    <label>TOTAL</label>
    <input type="text" name="total_id" placeholder="0" onchange="suma_final()">
</form>
```

Comment: Verifica la otra parte de la respuesta que agregue, el input de los checkbos en la parte de value es `$i` no `$id`